# What would this effect be called?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, effect

I came across this effect on codepen and I was wondering what would you call this? ([Taken from here](http://codepen.io/fralec/pen/xZBKzO))

```js
/* JS scripts are added see github repo for more 
https://github.com/fralec/ElegantJS */

$('#stay').elegant({
    clickNextToClose: true,
    newTab: true,
    facebook: {
        id: 'alec.vonbarnekow'
    },
    twitter: {
        id: 'fralec_'
    },
    github: {
        id: 'fralec'
    },
    website: {
        id: 'https://fralec.com'
    },
    instagram: {
        id: 'fralec__'
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #80339E;
    font-family: Verdana;
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 200px;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 4em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!-- head -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgit.com/fralec/elegantShareJS/master/script/elegant.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//rawgit.com/fralec/elegantShareJS/master/css/elegant.css">
<!-- body -->
<button id="stay">Stay in touch</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a fade transition with changes in opacity.

Answer (score 0):

Elegant is a custom function here.You will have to fork the code which has that library.
Here you can try to achieve same effect using jquery fadein and fadeout:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
       // $("#div1").fadeIn();
        $("#div2").fadeOut(3000);
        $("#div3").fadeIn(3000);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Demonstrate fadeIn() with different parameters.</p>

<button>Click to fade in boxes</button><br><br>

<div id="div2" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:block;background-color:red;position:absolute"></div><br>

<div id="div3" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:blue;position:absolute"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I haven't really learned javascript yet. Could you please give me an example of how you would do it?

Comment: I am trying to basically make a page transition, like in the codepen. So when I click the button it will fade into the page, and have an 'x' in the top right to go back to the home page.

Comment: Put an x inside div where required.Onclick apply similar method.

Comment: tru to to get first transition and post the code of div here. Will try to guide you from there

Comment: I just tried to do the first transition but I couldn't get it to work. Is there anyway you could help me figure out how to get the codepen that I linked to work. Cause it is exactly what I am looking for. http://codepen.io/fralec/pen/xZBKzO

Comment: Did you try forking it?